# How do I efficiently add text and drawn boxes on a PDF using ImageMagick?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagic to open a PDF, draw a couple of boxes with text labels on the PDF, and then resave it as a PDF.  This has been deceptively difficult for me to figure out how to do, but I got something working per this previous question: [imageMagick: How do I draw on one page of a pdf but keep the whole pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66093160/imagemagick-how-do-i-draw-on-one-page-of-a-pdf-but-keep-the-whole-pdf)

My test files, which were 3 pages, were processed fine.  However, when it went to QA, and it was tried with large files (some 30-50 pages, which will be normal use for this script) it kept timing out with messages like this:

```
    timeout [300000 ms] expired while executing [c:\IM\magick.exe -density 300 -compress ZIP c:\tempWorking\138.pdf[0-1] ( c:\tempWorking\138.pdf[2] -fill rgba(255, 214, 214,  0.7) -stroke #000f55 -draw rectangle 2145,742,3245,907 -fill #000 -stroke #000 -font Arial -pointsize 10 -draw text 2167,885 'Box 1: Test' -fill rgba(255, 214, 214,  0.7) -stroke #000f55 -draw rectangle 2145,896,3245,1061 -fill #000 -stroke #000 -font Arial -pointsize 10 -draw text 2167,1039 'Box 2: Test 2' -fill rgba(255, 214, 214,  0.7) -stroke #000f55 -draw rectangle 2145,1023,3245,1188 -fill #000 -stroke #000 -font Arial -pointsize 10 -draw text 2167,1166 'Box 2: Test 2' ) c:\tempWorking\138.pdf[3-18] c:\esigImgs\62\preview.pdf]
```

To break down that impenetrable wall of text, my script wrote out a command similar to this:

```
    c:\IM\magick.exe
            -density 300
            -compress ZIP 
                c:\tempWorking\138.pdf[0-1]
                (
                    c:\tempWorking\138.pdf[2]
                    -fill rgba(255, 214, 214,  0.7)
                    -stroke #000f55
                    -draw rectangle 2145,742,3245,907

                    -fill #000
                    -stroke #000
                    -font Arial
                    -pointsize 10
                    -draw text 2167,885 'Box 1: Test'

                    -fill rgba(255, 214, 214,  0.7)
                    -stroke #000f55
                    -draw rectangle 2145,896,3245,1061

                    -fill #000
                    -stroke #000
                    -font Arial
                    -pointsize 10
                    -draw text 2167,1039 'Box 2: Test 2'

                    -fill rgba(255, 214, 214,  0.7)
                    -stroke #000f55
                    -draw rectangle 2145,1023,3245,1188

                    -fill #000
                    -stroke #000
                    -font Arial
                    -pointsize 10
                    -draw text 2167,1166 'Box 2: Test 2'
                )
                c:\tempWorking\138.pdf[3-18]
                c:\esigImgs\62\preview.pdf
```

So we're taking some pages that are not altered, adding a page that is altered, then adding more pages that are not altered.  Production use of this will usually involve far more boxes and text being written to several pages.

I extended the timeout to 300s just to see what would happen.  Originally the timeout was set at 60 seconds, and I would really like it to take far less.  This was running on an AWS instance.  When I tested it locally it completed in around 60 seconds with the same file, but had mostly locked my cpu for that entire time.

What am I doing wrong and how can I approach making this process more efficient?

Comment: You may be running out of RAM if you have 30-50 pages at 300 dpi. So you could adjust your policy.xml file. It also has a "time" out entry that you can make longer.

Comment: `c:\tempWorking\138.pdf[0-1]` is process the first two pages, not just the one page.

Comment: Does it work at a lower density?

Comment: Imagemagick is going to rasterize your (vector?) PDF at 300 dpi for 30-50 pages. How big are you pages in inches? Do you have enough RAM to hold them all after rasterizing.  Your resulting PDF will be raster images in a vector PDF shell.  Imagemagick is not the best tool for doing what you want. It relies upon Ghostscript to rasterize.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks.  I know rasterizing and writing are not the most efficient approach.  However, when I tried to search for other products to achieve this goal I could not find one that was free and that provided enough information that I thought it could actually do this.  Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: @KJ This sounds like a much more efficient approach.  Is this something that can be done in ImageMagick?  Would you be able to write an answer with some further information on how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In comments you asked how to add vector info quickly to a source PDF via Image Magic appending data, I replied, it is best to use annotation by over stamping one PDF onto another, and there are  many different cross platform methods even using shell script as a rect and text pdf as the stamp.

However, it seems from the question your need is even simpler than that.

As an example to add text and boxes you could use cpdf, the advantage is the values can be easily set as variables for different situations. here I am using just page 1 (-range 1) but that same entry can be applied to a range of pages.

```
cpdf -add-rectangle "200 100" -pos-center "180 200" -color "red" -range 1 -outline earth.pdf AND -pos-center "180 210" -midline -font Helvetica -font-size 20 -add-text "Hello World!" -color "white" -opacity 1.0 -range 1 AND -pos-center "180 190" -midline -font Helvetica -font-size 20 -add-text "Hello USA!" -color "1.0 1.0 0.0" -opacity 1.0 -range 1 -o out.pdf
```

[image]

For more complex possibilities like multi line stamps there is a powerfully small cross platform tool at https://pdfcpu.io/core/stamp#examples
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  It may take me a bit to get the time to test this as this is a side project, but I will come back and mark this as the answer if this works out for me.  :)